# Hide jhipster config file or parameters from admin frontend

Tags: jhipster

We built a jhipster app, and like it, but its admin panel has all the configuration values available for all admins,is it a way to hide application-prod.yml or hide some values of it?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration properties displayed in admin panel are exposed by /management/configprops endpoint which is implemented by Spring Boot Actuator.

Actuator can be configured in application*.yml to sanitize sensible values: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-sanitize-sensible-values